# В чем различие между attribute от uniform?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Читаем:

> **Атрибуты (attribute)** — это свойство вершины. У вершины могут быть
>   различные атрибуты. Например, координаты положения в пространстве,
>   координаты вектора нормали, цвет. Кроме того, вы можете передавать в
>   вершинный шейдер какие-либо свои атрибуты. Важно понять, что атрибут —
>   это свойство вершины, и поэтому он должен быть задан для каждой
>   вершины. Атрибуты передаются в только вершинный шейдер. Атрибуты
>   доступны вершинному шейдеру только для чтения и не могут быть
>   перезаписаны.
>
> **Юниформы (uniform)** — это внешние данные, которые могут быть
>   использованы для расчетов, но не могут быть перезаписаны. Униформы
>   могут быть переданы как в вершинный, так и во фрагментный шейдеры.
>   Униформы никак не связаны с конкретной вершиной и являются глобальными
>   константами. Например, в качестве униформ можно передать в шейдер
>   координаты источника света и координаты глаза (камеры).

***Для первых:***

Атрибуты доступны вершинному шейдеру только для чтения и не могут быть перезаписаны.

***Для вторых:***

Юниформы (uniform) — это внешние данные, которые могут быть использованы для расчетов, но не могут быть перезаписаны.

***Вывод:***

и те и другие можно читать но нельзя перезаписать.

***Вопрос:***

Чем они различаются?

Answer (score 3):

**Униформ** - это константа переданная программистом в шейдер, где она будет использоваться как константа.

**Атрибут** же - это константа **вершины**. Атрибут будет использован для расчёта свойств вершины, например, для вычисления текстурной координаты вершины, потом эти рассчитанные данные будут интерполированы для использования во фрагментном шейдере.

У каждой вершины свои атрибуты, которые используются в вершинном шейдере, а униформы - это просто константы, которые используются в обоих шейдерах. А как раз **вариинг** - это рассчитанное значение для вершины, которое во фрагментном шейдере будет интерполировано в зависимости от расстояния до вершин.

Программист передаёт данные для вершин в атрибутах - координаты, текстурные координаты, нормаль, цвет, да вообще на самом деле что угодно ещё. В шейдере это будет выглядеть как одна переменная, например, цвет, но - в реальности для каждой вершины в атрибут будут заноситься значения именно для этой вершины, и будет вызываться вершинный шейдер. Если смотреть на вершинный шейдер как на функцию/метод, то атрибуты - это параметры этой функции, а сама функция вызывается видеокартой для каждой вершины.

Задачей программиста же является загрузить в видеокарту атрибуты **для каждой** вершины. То есть имеем, например, 20 вершин, значит надо передать 20 координат, 20 вершиных координат, 20 нормалей и пр. (всё, что нужно для конкретного шейдера). Видеокарта получает эти массивы. В начале отрисовки происходит "обсчёт" вершин. Для каждой вершины из массивов берутся соответствующие значения атрибутов и подставляются в вершинный вертекс, он выполняется, и производит вычисления для конкретной вершины основываясь на именно её атрибутах.

Comment: а почему в качестве атрибута не использовать униформ с соответствующим типом и не вычислять все остальное из нее? Зачем такая специализация?

Comment: Простым языком атрибут - нормаль, позиция, цвет вершины, т.е. они per-vertex. Униформа - глобальная константа для всей шейдерной программы, проще говоря - per-shader program.  Атрибуты обычно хранятся в буфере на видеокарте, а при отрисовке просто подтягиваются в шейдеры, т.е. нет нагрузки на шины, а униформы задаются через код, выполняемый на процессоре. Униформы можно использовать для цвета/направления источника цвета, текстуры etc.

Comment: Переписал, кажется стало доступнее

Answer (score 1):

Еще добавлю примеры:

Для `uniform` это глобальные, вроде параметров освещения, текстур модели, каких-либо коэффициентов. Они видны **во всех шейдерах, собранных в программу**

Для `attributes` это цвет, нормаль, uv, позиция, тангент и т.д.